# How do we extends Request and Response in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I need add properties in Request and Response interfaces. I'm using nodejs with typescript. I don't know because it doesn't read the interface.. My configuration:

src/app/types/express.d.ts

```
declare namespace Express {
  interface Request {
    database?: string;
    userId?: string;
  }

  interface Response {
    message?: string;
    data?: ''
  }
}
```

/.tsconfig

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es2018",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "typeRoots": ["./types"]
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "src/types"
        
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Error

```
src/app/middleware/auth.middleware.ts(29,15): error TS2339: Property 'database' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
```

Has anyone had this problem? I don't want to use my own interface and extend Response or Request.....

Can we use generics in the response.data?? Something like

```
export interface Response<T> {
  success: boolean
  message: string
  errors: {}
  data: T
}
```